# CSS paths are changes in Url rewriting in php

Tags: php, css, .htaccess

When I am using htaccess file, CSS files are not loading. Can anyone provide me code for CSS get to work?

Code of .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^products/([a-zA-Z]+)$ /products/$1 [R]
RewriteRule ^products/([a-zA-Z]+)/$ productinfo.php?prodID=$1
```

Answer (score 1):

Your conditions will make the rewrite rules apply whenever a file or directory with that path **exists** (e.g. if a css exists, instead of loading it it will rewrite to what you specified).

This is probably exactly the opposite of what you want, **you probably want to rewrite whenever the user didn't request a real file**, e.g.:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

This will run the RewriteRules only if the requested path doesn't match a real file and doesn't match a real directory.